# xfce4-terminal on Plasma change window color/style to dark

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, kde, xfce

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 with Plasma. My terminal is xfce4-terminal. I'm looking for change default window style (white/gray - in the picture) to dark. How can I do that?

[image]

I'm trying do that using `xfce4-appearance-settings` but it's not working. How can I do that? As you see all xfce windows are in white style.

[image]

My plasma settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[try this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDpLz.png)

to open directly this^ setting window, run:

```
kcmshell5 style
```

If this^ not help - try this :

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#GTK_application_appearance

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications